# Is there a way to get the Controller Type through the ASP.NET MVC3 pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection

I need to get hold of the Attributes on another Controller (i.e. not the current one being executed).

One way to do this is as follows:

```
    Type controllerType = Type.GetType("App1.UI.Web.Controllers." + controllerName + "Controller", true);
    object[] controllerAttributes = controllerType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Is there a better, less brittle, way to do the same using the MVC pipeline?  I don't want to instantiate the controller, I just want it's attributes.

Comment: where is the `controllerName` variable coming from? and what sort of information does the attribute provide?

Comment: Why are you trying to access a different controller than the one being executing?

Comment: If you're in the pipeline you should be able to use ControllerDescriptor to get the name of the Controller Name and then use reflection to locate the type and its attributes

Comment: We need to get attributes on another controller for a custom security-aware alternative to Html.ActionLink and Html.RouteLink. The attribute is a sub-class of AuthorizeAttribute which has additional security checks built in. Using the new ActionLink and RouteLink methods we can generate Anchors or Spans depending on whether or not the user has access to the action that the links refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you get rolling too far, keep in mind that a Controller doesn't have to end with the suffix "Controller". The default naming convention for MVC controllers is to append the word "Controller" on to the class. So your defaults are "HomeController" and "AboutController". You could easily create a class called "MyHome" or "Dashboard" and have it inherit from Controller and it would be a controller without having the "Controller" suffix.

I had created a route constraint in the past. Here is a snippet of code I used:

```
 List<Type> _type = Assembly
                            .GetCallingAssembly()
                            .GetTypes()
                            .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller)))
                            .ToList()
```

What the code does is looks in the current assembly for all classes that are a controller. You could also add in some code in to the where like :

```
 .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller)) && type.Name.ToLower() == "homecontroller")
```

Comment: I would add that you may want to use a static IEnumerable (List, array, etc) of types and store Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes() in it and then apply your where filter on the list of types. This should improve speed as it will keep the list in memory depending on how frequently you will need to call it. In my opinion it could be static because the list of types should not change during the application life cycle, in order to change types you would have to deploy new code which would cause an application recycle.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks Splash-x.